# Regex condition in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have state numbers and state letters of vehicles according to States in DB. State numbers can be old and new type.

Example of new types of state number.

- 273KL**01**
- 002UK**02**
- 098KZ**03**
- 120US**04**
- ...

Example of old types of state number.

- **R**575KMM
- **A**887KDN
- **M**784LKA
- **X**647DUA
- ...

Bold characters indicates specified State.

User will input his car's state number and choose State. I need to validate If state number can be registered in chosen State. If it not possible(wrong user input) I will show him message like *"You entered wrong state number or State"*  .

I have done this with ***If-Else*** statement. But I want to know another way with ***regex***.

As I think, here will be two steps of condition.

1. Check if number is old type(starts with letter), if true get from DB state letter and check with ***regex*** statements.
2. If case 1 is false, I get from DB state digits and check with ***regex*** statements.

I have ***regex*** statement for the first condition:

`^(?i)f` - Where state letter is `f`.

- What will be regex statement for my second conditon?
- Or can be it done(two steps both) with one ***regex*** statements?

Comment: Wait. How `Basci98` is true?

Comment: @Thomas, it another example. Here it starts with specified letter(in this example it is **B**) and end with 2 digit.

Comment: So your words need to start by **any letter** ?

Comment: @ШыназАлиш What do you mean, another example? So do you want to check for `A` and `02` or `12`, or do you just want to accept any letter at the beginning and any two numbers at the end?

Comment: @poke, YES. But specified any letter at the beginning and specified any two digits at the end. Specified two digits, because it can be **02**, not only **2**.

Comment: @Thomas, I rewrite my question.

Comment: Ok, see my answer then.

Comment: The question is much clearer now, with realistic examples of number plates.  Unfortunately, all the answers are based on the original examples, and they all have to be completely rewritten.  The `Basic98` example was especially confusing, because a number plate **cannot** begin with a letter **and** end with digits, according to your new examples.

Comment: *“I have done this with If-Else statement”* – Maybe you could show the code for what you have done, and then explain clearly what you want to change about it?

Comment: You should consider accepting the answer that suited your needs or tell us what's wrong with the answers provided...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you further explained that you actually do want to match *any* letter at the beginning, and *any* two digits at the end of the string, using a regular expression is indeed the shortest way to solve this.

```
Regex re = new Regex("^[a-z].*[0-9]{2}$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Console.WriteLine(re.IsMatch("Apple02")); // true
Console.WriteLine(re.IsMatch("Arrow")); // false
Console.WriteLine(re.IsMatch("45Alty12")); // false
Console.WriteLine(re.IsMatch("Basci98")); // true
```

---

Otherwise, if your requirement is simple, e.g. just the letter `A` or `a` at the beginning, and `12` or `02` at the end, then you can also solve this easily without regular expressions:

```
bool Match(string s)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
        return false;

    if (s[0] != 'a' && s[0] != 'A')
        return false;

    return s.EndsWith("02") || s.EndsWith("12");
}
```

Examples:

```
Console.WriteLine(Match("Apple02")); // true
Console.WriteLine(Match("Arrow")); // false
Console.WriteLine(Match("45Alty12")); // false
Console.WriteLine(Match("a12")); // true
Console.WriteLine(Match("a")); // false
Console.WriteLine(Match("12")); // false
```

---

Of course you can also expand this to fit your more complex requirement. In your case, you could use `char.IsLetter` and `char.IsDigit` to make the checks:

```
bool Match(string s)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
        return false;

    return s.Length > 2 && char.IsLetter(s[0]) &&
        char.IsDigit(s[s.Length - 1]) && char.IsDigit(s[s.Length - 2]);
}
```

Note that the `IsLetter` method also accepts letters from non-English alphabets, so you might need to change that. You could alternatively make a comparison like this:

```
bool Match(string s)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
        return false;

    return s.Length > 2 &&
        ((s[0] >= 'a' && s[0] <= 'z') || (s[0] >= 'A' && s[0] <= 'Z'))
        char.IsDigit(s[s.Length - 1]) && char.IsDigit(s[s.Length - 2]);
}
```

Comment: Life is better without Regex... But it's so much funnier :D

Comment: s.StartsWith("a") || s.StartsWith("A") would be better in my opinion

Comment: @AwaisMahmood Directly accessing the character should be faster though, and with the `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` check before we ensured that we can access the index. But yeah, you can totally use `StartsWith` here :)

Comment: @Poke op says `Basci98` should return true.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I deliberately ignored that since I highly believe that it was a mistake. I value the written out condition descriptions a lot higher than a `TRUE` in some example ;)

Comment: Re-reading the question, I think OP means start with any letter and finish with two digits - the bolded A and 02/12 are just examples.  It's really unclear :(

Comment: `Char.IsLetter(s[0])` should work if the op needs any letter (providing Latin letters count etc) but definitely needs to be defined by OP first

Comment: @poke,  I rewrite my question.

Comment: @JamesThorpe,  I rewrite my question.

Comment: @ШыназАлиш You should have enough information from all the answers to solve the problem yourself now.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you need:

```
^[Aa].*[01][2]$
```

With a few explanations:

```
^ assert position at start of a line
[Aa] match a single character present in the list below
    Aa a single character in the list Aa literally

.* matches any character (except newline)
    Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

[01] match a single character present in the list below
    01 a single character in the list 01 literally

[2] match a single character present in the list below
    2 the literal character 2

$ assert position at end of a line
```

---

If you need it to start with **any letter** :

```
^[A-Za-z].*[01][2]$
```

---

#### Given your edit:

I would use this regex:

```
^[A-Z].{6}|.{5}\d{2}$
```

Which guaranties that the input is:

- Of length 7;
- Start with a capital letter **OR** finishes with two digit

Comment: you forgot to make it case insensitive